# Questions on BETWEEN syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, between

I'm working on a script which retrieves the latest balance for an account that is earlier or equal to a given date. For example, if the last movement of the account was on Jan.5, and I input Jan.8 on the script, it would have to retrieve the balance back in Jan.5 . of course, if there is any movement in the account on Jan.8, then it would retrieve the balance at Jan.8 . Each balance though, is valid for a given date range, as dictated by the columns `BAL_DATE` and `END_BAL_DATE`.

This script works, butI find it very unusual since the position of the values and the expressions are swapped:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tbaadm.gstt
WHERE
    gl_sub_head_code = '12403'
    AND
    crncy_code in ('USD','HKD')
    AND
    sol_id = 5001
    AND
    last_day('29-OCT-2015') BETWEEN BAL_DATE and END_BAL_DATE
```

Is it okay if I use this script? Or is it bad practice?

Comment: What do you mean my `I find it very unusual since the position of the values and the expressions are swapped`?

Comment: Please provide the table schema (by way of a `CREATE TABLE` statement).

Comment: the usual syntax of a BETWEEN statement is supposed to be `WHERE [expression] BETWEEN [value1] and [value2]`. In this case, it should be `WHERE bal_date BETWEEN '1-DEC-2015' AND '31-DEC-2015'`.

Comment: @Dai here you go:

`CREATE TABLE GLSH_TRAN_TABLE
(
  SOL_ID                    VARCHAR2(8 CHAR),
  BAL_DATE                  DATE,
  GL_SUB_HEAD_CODE          VARCHAR2(5 CHAR),
  CRNCY_CODE                VARCHAR2(3 CHAR),
  DEL_FLG                   CHAR(1 BYTE),
  TOT_DR_BAL                NUMBER(25,4),
  TOT_CR_BAL                NUMBER(25,4),
  END_BAL_DATE              DATE,
  BANK_ID                   VARCHAR2(8 CHAR)
)`

Comment: I don't see any issue with the query. The syntax for the `BETWEEN` clause is just fine. What is your concern?

Comment: @LalitKumarB my question is, can I use the `BETWEEN` clause in that way? It's supposed to be `WHERE [expression] BETWEEN [value1] and [value2]` but what I did was `WHERE [value] BETWEEN [expression1] and [expression2]`

Comment: @JamesP **A BETWEEN condition determines whether the value of one expression is in an interval defined by two other expressions.**. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the **[documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm)**,

> BETWEEN Conditions
>
> A BETWEEN condition determines whether the value of one expression is
>   in an interval defined by two other expressions.

Basically, you are comparing **two expressions** to **an expression**.

```
last_day('29-OCT-2015') BETWEEN BAL_DATE and END_BAL_DATE
```

In your query, you are comparing **expr 1** i.e. `last_day('29-OCT-2015')` to **expr 2** `BAL_DATE` and **expr 3** `END_BAL_DATE`.

The entire **BETWEEN condition** is **internally interpreted** as:

```
last_day('29-OCT-2015') >= BAL_DATE AND last_day('29-OCT-2015') <= END_BAL_DATE
```

Comment: wow, I didn't know values could also be used as expressions. So the script I used really is valid. I like how I learn something new everyday. Thanks for this, marking as answer.

Comment: @JamesP With any SQL function, always remember, the value is evaluated from the **expression**. Similar confusion happens with developers when they use **CASE** in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your concern, note that in SQL, you can use multiple where clause by using `and` condition.

```
select ....
from ....
where <condition1> 
and <condition2>
...
```

So the between query is correctly used. You can use between query in `where` clause and rest all in `and` and you will get exact same result. So your query is similar to

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tbaadm.gstt
WHERE
    last_day('29-OCT-2015') BETWEEN BAL_DATE and END_BAL_DATE 
    and
    gl_sub_head_code = '12403'
    AND
    crncy_code in ('USD','HKD')
    AND
    sol_id = 5001
```